# Changing the category page heading on my WordPress theme for a specific page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

1. Go to my website http://survived2012shirt.com/ebjc/category/shabbot_shalom/
2. Take notice how it says "the Golden Vision Award" in giant the blue banner below the menu bar
3. I want to change what it says in the Giant blue banner to "Shabbot Shalom". for that particular page. It is displaying the title of the most recent blog post under the category. Shabbot Shalom is the title of my category.

   4. I have several other category pages on my website. I will want to change what it says in the giant blue banner on these pages to different phrases depending on what the page is about.

The theme that I am using is Adore Church by Imithemes. If I need to change something in the code please let me know which file I should go to, what I specifically need to change in the code.

Thanks so much for you help

Comment: You probably have to edit your archive page code to use `<?php single_cat_title( '' ); ?>` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title

Comment: @Ross: u can use <?php is_category( $category ); ?> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category